# How to compare json file with expected result in Python 3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need to prepare test which will be comparing content of .json file with expected result (we want to check if values in .json are correctly generated by our dev tool). 
For test I will use robot framework or unittests but I don't know yet how to parse correctly json file.
Json example:

```
{
    "Customer": [{
            "Information": [{
                    "Country": "",
                    "Form": ""
                }
            ],
            "Id": "110",
            "Res": "",
            "Role": "Test",
            "Limit": ["100"]
        }]
}
```

So after I execute this:

```
with open('test_json.json') as f:
    hd = json.load(f)
```

I get dict `'hd'` where key is:

```
dict_keys(['Customer'])
```

and values:

```
dict_values([[{'Information': [{'Form': '', 'Country': ''}], 'Role': 'Test', 'Id': '110', 'Res': '', 'Limit': ['100']}]])
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get to only one value from Dict(e.g: Role: Test), because I can get only extract whole value. I can prepare a long string to compare with but it is not best solution for tests.

Any ideas how I can get to only one row from `.json` file?

Comment: why? 
it will resolve my problem?

Comment: you can access `Test` with `_role = hd['Customer'][0]['Role']`

Comment: @glibdud youre right, my bad. I deleted that comment.

Comment: You just do `values[0]['Role']`

Comment: @AliYılmaz you mean: print(hd['Customer'][0]['Role'])?, what [0] means here - I am noob in python :D

Comment: @pyton17 thats ok. Well, the [0] means we're trying to access 0th element in an array. Inside the main json file, there is a single key, `Customer`, and this key's value is an array. We want to access the array first, which can be accessed using `hd['Customer']`. After that, we want to access to the 1st element (0th index) inside array, which is the whole JSON body, including `Information`, `Id`, `Res`, `Role` and `Limit`.

Comment: @JakubBláha *print(hdfs.values[0]['Role'])* this should work?

Comment: e.g. if you want to repeatedly access to this dictionary inside array, you can assign it to a simpler name, say, `myDictionary`. You can do it by typing `myDictionary=hd['Customer'][0]`. After that, your goal is simplified to a single lookup, such as `myrole = myDictionary['Role']` and `myid = myDictionary['Id']`.

Comment: `print(list(hdfs.values())[0]['Role'])`. But you have to tweak the indexing.

Comment: @AliYılmaz and how I can get to "Country" from "Information"? It is possible

Comment: It's the same thing. If you want to get item from a list u use `[index]`. With a dictionary it's `[key]`. The json file is made of dictionaries and lists. With this information u should be able to figure it out :)

Comment: **print(list(hdfs.values())[0]['Role'])** - this one is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has single key 'Customer' and it has a value of list type. So when you ppass `dict_keys(['Customer'])` you are getting list value.

```
>>> hd['Customer']
[{'Id': '110', 'Role': 'Test', 'Res': '', 'Information': [{'Form': '', 'Country': ''}], 'Limit': ['100']}]
```

First element in list:

```
>>> hd['Customer'][0]
{'Id': '110', 'Role': 'Test', 'Res': '', 'Information': [{'Form': '', 'Country': ''}], 'Limit': ['100']}
```

Now access inside dict structure using:

```
>>> hd['Customer'][0]['Role']
'Test'
```

Comment: Great! Thanks - now I understand

Comment: @pyton17 please accept my answer and upvote if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can compare the dict that you loaded (say `hd`) to the expected results dict (say `expected_dict`) by running

```
hd.items() == expected_dict.items()
```

Comment: why test on items when you can just compare the dicts ?

Comment: I cannot compare whole dicts, other files can be changed. I need to compare only one filed.